# caml query issue A or B

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, caml-query

I have an issue with caml `or` query problem:

```
 <Where>
  <Or>
   <Eq>
     <FieldRef Name='Editor'/><Value Type='User'>x</Value>
  </Eq>
  <Eq>   
     <FieldRef Name='Editor'/><Value Type='User'>y</Value>
  </Eq>
  <Eq><FieldRef Name='Envoye_vers_Directeur' /><Value Type='Boolean'>0</Value>
  </Eq>
</Or>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

CAML can only have two conditions per group (you have three), so you need to nest one of your statements.  Try this:

```
<Where>
    <Or>
        <Or>
            <Eq>
                <FieldRef Name='Editor'/><Value Type='User'>abdellatif</Value>
            </Eq>
            <Eq>   
                <FieldRef Name='Editor'/><Value Type='User'>system</Value>
            </Eq>
        </Or>
        <Eq>
            <FieldRef Name='Envoye_vers_Directeur' /><Value Type='Boolean'>0</Value>
        </Eq>
    </Or>
</Where>
```